# How to access Raspberrypi via SSH after running a .py file at startup using systemd?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, systemd

I've set a .py file to run at startup of my Raspberry according to this guide : https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/

Method 4: Systemd

I did exactly as the tutorial, and the file does play at startup as expected. However, since that moment i've been unable to access the Raspberry via SSH or VNC, I ping to the Raspberry Address and I got positive response, but when I try to connect via SSH I get

"ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.250 port 22: Connection refused"

Since i'm working headless i'm unable to check what's wrong.

Any advice? thanks in advance!

Comment: What ssh command are you using?

Comment: ssh pi@192.168.1.250

Comment: prior to implementing the .py file it was the one I used and it worked without issue

Comment: could you share the content of the python script you are running?

Comment: DId you try to run your .py script in a screen ?

Answer (score 1):

Take the SD card out of the Raspberry Pi and put it in another computer. Create a file called `ssh` in the `boot` filesystem. Use `touch ssh` to create the file.

Put SD card back in Raspberry Pi and reboot. You will be able to `ssh` into it, then use `sudo raspi-config` to enable `ssh` permanently.

Comment: Thank you for your response, eventually i was able to see the problem (had to connect the raspberry to an HDMI screen, the issue was that after running the py file, the system didnt load the user interface, I suspect that the SSH service didn't started either, thank you!